# Soundcloud 401 error/invalid grant with PHP wrapper

Tags: php, soundcloud

We've just started getting an `401 - invalid_grant` error when attempting to upload files using the SoundCloud library [mptre/php-soundcloud](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud).

I get the same error when I try to regenerate a token:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token?client_id=ID_HERE&client_secret=SECRET_HERE&redirect_uri={this is actually blank on our apps page}&grant_type=authorization_code&code=XXXX
```

My assumption is that we need to refresh the auth token, but I thought we set it to non-expiring.

How can I prevent this `401` error and upload our audio via the API?

Any help would be really appreciated .

Comment: Link to [Soundcloud Status](https://status.soundcloud.com/) blog.